# Monit does not recognize memory used by monitored process

Tags: monitoring, osx-yosemite, sidekiq, monit, sidekiq-monitor

I'm running `sidekiq` on OSX 10.10.4, using `monit`, with the goal of restarting the process when total memory balloons over a certain level. However, `monit` thinks that the monitored `sidekiq` process does not consume any memory. `monit` instead sees all memory usage as system usage.

Here is the output of `monit status`, while `sidekiq` is running (started with `monit start all`:

```
Process 'sidekiq'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  pid                               414
  parent pid                        1
  uid                               501
  effective uid                     501
  gid                               20
  uptime                            0m 
  children                          1
  memory                            0 B
  memory total                      0 B
  memory percent                    0.0%
  memory percent total              0.0%
  cpu percent                       0.0%
  cpu percent total                 0.0%
  data collected                    Wed, 05 Aug 2015 09:57:21

System 'me-macbook-pro.local'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  load average                      [1.82] [1.31] [0.59]
  cpu                               11.3%us 4.6%sy
  memory usage                      2.3 GB [56.2%]
  swap usage                        0 B [0.0%]
  data collected                    Wed, 05 Aug 2015 09:57:21
```

**What do I need to do to get `monit` to recognize that the `sidekiq` process is the one consuming the memory?**

For context, I have pasted my `.monitrc` and associated scripts below.

```
### .monitrc

set daemon 20
set httpd port 2812
  allow me:password_censored

check process sidekiq with pidfile /Users/me/app/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
  start program = "/bin/bash /Users/me/app/start_sidekiq.sh" with timeout 20 seconds
  stop program = "/bin/bash /Users/me/app/stop_sidekiq.sh" with timeout 20 seconds 
  if totalmem is greater than 150 MB for 2 cycles then restart
```

---

```
### start_sidekiq.sh
#!/bin/sh

cd /Users/me/app

bundle exec sidekiq -C /Users/me/app/config/sidekiq.yml \
  -P /Users/me/app/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid \
  -L /Users/me/app/log/sidekiq.log \
  -d
```

---

```
### stop_sidekiq.sh
#!/bin/sh

kill -TERM `cat /Users/me/app/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid`
```